# Более лаконичное решение на linq

Tags: c#, linq

Как заменить одним лаконичным выражением на Linq следующие строчки:

```
foreach (Company company in companies)
            {
                List<CheckPoint> checkPoints = await _context.CheckPoints
                    .Where(cp => cp.CompanyId == company.Id).ToListAsync();
            }
```

Модели:

```
public class CheckPoint
{
    [Key]
    public ulong Id { get; private set; }

    [Column("Name", TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    [Column("CompanyId", TypeName = "decimal(20, 0)")]
    public ulong CompanyId { get; private set; }

    public Company? Company { get; private set; }

    public CheckPoint(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        CompanyId = default;
        Company = default;
    }
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public ulong Id { get; private set; }

    [Column("FullName", TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
    public string FullName { get; private set; }

    public List<User>? Users { get; private set; }

    public List<CheckPoint>? CheckPoints { get; private set; }

    public Company(string fullName)
    {
        Id = default;
        FullName = fullName;
        Users = new List<User>();
        CheckPoints = new List<CheckPoint>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Выражение бессмысленное, получает данные и тут же забывает об этом. Можно весь цикл удалить.

Comment: Ну и крепите код текстом, не картинками.

Comment: Исправил.
Выражение нужно заменить с foreach, я его специально тут и оставил.
Мне нужно получить все CheckPoint`ы, которые существуют в компаниях в списке companies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<CheckPoint> checkPoints = await _context.CheckPoints
    .Where(cp => companies.Select(c => c.Id).Contains(cp.CompanyId))
    .ToListAsync();
```

или

```
List<CheckPoint> checkPoints = await _context.CheckPoints
    .Where(cp => companies.Any(c => c.Id == cp.CompanyId))
    .ToListAsync();
```

не знаю, что будет быстрее.